# finding a surjective function if $A=\left \{1,3,6,7,9 \right \},B=\left \{5,8,3,7 \right \}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given $A=\left \{1,3,6,7,9  \right \},B=\left \{5,8,3,7  \right \}$

How can I define a function $f:A\rightarrow B$ so that $f$ is a surjective function?

I can write it in pairs such as: $(1,5),(3,3),(6,3),(7,7),(9,8)$ but don't know how to write it i a formal way.

Thanks.

Comment: i can do it in pairs like $(1,5),(3,3)$ and so but don't know how to write it in a formal way.

Comment: Write that, in more detail, in the question.

Comment: What you have written is perfectly acceptable. Each point in $A$ is carried to a unique point in $B$ (so it is a function), and each point in $B$ occurs as a "target" of some (not necessarily unique!) point in $A$, so the function is indeed surjective. Nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(1)=5$$
$$f(3)=5$$
$$f(6)=8$$
$$f(7)=3$$
$$f(9)=7$$
Just one of the many surjective functions that can be defined on those two sets. Basically you have to define a  surjective function that maps every element from $A$ to $B$.

Answer (score 8):

You can just list $f(1)=5,f(3)= \dots$ making sure that all the elements of $B$ appear on the right side of the equals signs.  This is the definition of surjective.  Listing it in pairs is fine, too.  If you take the list of pairs you added and put them in braces, that set is a function from $A \to B$.  There is no need for a "concise rule" when defining a function-you just have to give a single appropriate output for any appropriate input, which you have done.